# Use of static private attributes

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding the use of private static attributes in a class :

-> private means the attributes will only be accessible from the class itself if I'm correct

-> static indicates the attributes belong to the class itself and not the object and, if I'm still correct, which permit to access it without creating an object

So, I can't imagine any use of a private static attribute.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Kenshin

Comment: In one word, Singleton.

Comment: You're not correct. Its also available to anything friended, and certainly available via any protected or public member function offering exposure via value, reference, or address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said it yourself: if you want a variable associated with the class but not part of any object (`static`), that can only be accessed within the class itself (`private`).

As a concrete example, here's a class that counts instances of itself:

```
class countable {
private:
    static unsigned count;
public:
    countable() {++count;}
    countable(const countable&) {++count;}
    ~countable() {--count;}

    static unsigned instance_count() {return count;}
};
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Indeed, it should be static, thanks.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for the example. But still, is this something widely used or is it usefull in some rare cases ?

Thanks again

Comment: @Kenshin It is widely used in rare cases. If you need it, you use it; if you don't, you don't! Assigning internal ID numbers could be [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26594296/616460). Use your imagination.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers ! I thing I got it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that might expand your imagination:

```
class Singleton
{
   public:
       static Singleton* getInstance();
       ~Singleton();
   private:
       Singleton();
       static Singleton* instance;
};
```

Comment: Why would you return a pointer and not a reference from `getInstance`?

Comment: @rightføld: It's just an example to answer OP's question. Of course you can declare a `private: static Singleton instance` and return a reference to it.

Comment: @barakmanos: why would you let the choice of implementation (pointer or direct instance) dictate the interface (pointer or reference returned)?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: For the sake of answering this question, I did not focus on designing the interface before choosing the implementation. Instead, I merely provided a usage example of a private static attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example that might [expand your imagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26594218/616460):

```
class NotAThreadSafeExample {
public:
    NotAThreadSafeExample () { ++ debugReferenceCount; }
    ~NotAThreadSafeExample () { -- debugReferenceCount; }
    static int getDebugReferenceCount () { return debugReferenceCount; }
private:
    static int debugReferenceCount;
};
```

Or:

```
class Example {
private:
    static const int FIXED_COLUMN_WIDTH = 32;
};
```

Or maybe even something like this, where appropriate (`atomicIncrement` left to your imagination, e.g. [`InterlockedIncrement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows or [`__sync_add_and_fetch()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins) with GCC; integral type `record_id_t` chosen accordingly):

```
class Record {
public:
    Record () : id(atomicIncrement(&nextId)) { }
    record_id_t getId () const { return id; }
private:
    static volatile record_id_t nextId;
    record_id_t id;
};
```

Or any other use you can imagine for a `static` variable that is not accessible outside of a class or its `friend`s.

Answer (score 0):

A `friend` class or function could access this static member.